# Can someone explain this quirk in applying functions in k3?

Tags: kdb

Can someone explain this behavior of k3 to me or point me in the right direction? I am using kona.

```
>  (1e2>+/-1#){x,1+-1#x}/1
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100
>  ((1e2)>-1#){x,1+-1#x}/1
1
```

Specifically, why `(1e2>-1#)` or `((1e2)>-1#)` does not work like `(1e2>+/-1#)`. I find it confusing, since `+/-1#` and `-1#` are the same in my mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(1e2>+/-1#){x,1+-1#x}/1
```

This keeps on applying the function `{x,1+-1#x}` on the result(starting with 1) until `(1e2>+/-1#)` conition becomes true. / is acting as an over operator here.

function  `{x,1+-1#x}` is just taking the last element of the list, adding 1 to it and then appends it at the end of the list.
`(1e2>+/-1#)` is the condition which checks if 100 is greater than last element of the list.

Comment: I should phrase my question better, but why is `((1e2)>-1#)` not a valid condition?

Comment: the condition should return a boolean atom(1b or 0b), -1# returns a list of count 1(and not an atom). so if you do (1e2)>(any list) , it will return you a list, hence not a valid condition. +/ basically converts a list of count 1 to an atom.